# Solving $x([\frac{x}{2\pi}]+1)=100$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I wonder how to solve this equation  $x([\frac{x}{2\pi}]+1)=100$ with algebra. Here $[ ]$ is the integral function. I can use trial and error to find out integral solution say $x=25$ but it seems I can't easily show with algebra that there is only one solution existing.

Comment: well, floor(x/2pi) + 1 must be integer, so x must be a factor of 100 also. you only need to check factors of 100

Comment: @qwr Not really, a rational number times integer can also be an integer, what if $a$ is a rational number say $\frac{100}{21}$ and $[x/2\pi]+1]=21$. I knew this is not a solution but $a$ can definitely be some non-integral values sometimes

Comment: ok what about putting bounds on floor(x/2pi). then you should see only a small range of numbers could work

Comment: Note that $\lfloor \frac{2\pi}{x}\rfloor+1$ is nondecreasing and $\frac{100}{x}$ is strictly decreasing. As $x=0$ is not a solution, if the system has a solution(in which 25 is one), then it must have just one positive solution and at most one negative solution. It seems that there is no negative solution by graph, though.

Comment: What's the integral function?

Answer (score 1):

Your question resembles a lot like: find the zeroes $y=x \cdot (\frac{x}{2 \pi} + 1) - 100$. You might expect a parabola-like graph, and indeed, this is what the graph looks like:

[image]

So, your question comes down to the question: are there one or two zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

We denote $\left[ \frac{x}{2\pi} \right]$ by $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi} \right \rfloor$. Let $n = \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2 \pi} \right \rfloor$. We have $n \neq 0$. Also note that $2\pi(n-1) \le x < 2\pi n$ and $x= \frac{100}{n}$. Therefore, for each integer satisfying $\pi n - \pi \le \frac{50}{n} < \pi n$, there corresponds a unique solution. This inequality is equivalent to
$$
-5 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}<n\leq \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{200+\pi }{\pi }}\lor 5
   \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}<n\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{200+\pi }{\pi }}
$$
which reduces to, approximately,
$$
-3.98942<n\leq -3.52063\lor 3.98942<n\leq 4.52063
$$
Therefore, the solution of the equation $ x\left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2π} \right\rfloor +1 \right)=100 $ is unique.

*Remark 1:* The value of the unique solution is $x=25$.

*Remark 2:* One can argue by dividing the cases $n<0$ and $n>0$ separately and using monotonicity of the function; $n \le -1$, the function is apparently decreasing and $n \ge 1$, the functionn if apparently increasing. Sketching the graph for $-4 \le n  \le 4$ should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

For all real $w$,

$$\lfloor w \rfloor \le w <\lfloor w \rfloor + 1. \tag{2}$$

So

$$w < \lfloor w \rfloor + 1 \le w + 1. \tag{3}$$

This gives rise to two cases of interest:

$$\begin{cases}w^2 < f(w) \le w(w+1), & w > 0 \\ w(w+1) \le f(w) < w^2, & w < 0, \end{cases} \tag{4}$$

where

$$f(w) = w(\lfloor w \rfloor + 1). \tag{5}$$

The given equation corresponds to solving $f(w) = \frac{50}{\pi}$, where $w = \frac{x}{2\pi}$.  Hence we have the bounds

$$\begin{cases}w^2 < \frac{50}{\pi} \le w(w+1), & w > 0 \\
w(w+1) < \frac{50}{\pi} \le w^2, & w < 0, \end{cases} \tag{6}$$
which in turn implies
$$\begin{cases} \frac{-1 + \sqrt{\frac{200}{\pi} + 1}}{2} \le w < \sqrt{\frac{50}{\pi}}, & w > 0 \\
\frac{-1 - \sqrt{\frac{200}{\pi} + 1}}{2} < w \le -\sqrt{\frac{50}{\pi}}, & w < 0,\end{cases} \tag{7}$$
hence
$$ \lfloor w \rfloor  \in \{-5, -4, 3\}. \tag{8}$$
We now address each case individually:
$$\begin{cases}
x \in (-\pi - \sqrt{\pi(\pi+200)}, -8\pi), & \lfloor w \rfloor = -5, \\
x \in [-8\pi, -10\sqrt{2\pi}], & \lfloor w \rfloor = -4, \\
x \in [6\pi, 10\sqrt{2\pi}), & \lfloor w \rfloor = 3. \end{cases} \\ \tag{9}$$
All that remains is to now evaluate $$\frac{100}{\lfloor w \rfloor + 1}$$ for each case and determine which intervals contain this value, hence admits a solution.

The first case requires $x = -25$, but $-8\pi < -25$, so no solution exists in this interval.

The second case requires $x = -\frac{100}{3}$, but $-\frac{100}{3} < -8\pi$, so again, no solution in this interval.

The last case requires $x = 25$, which is just barely inside the interval, as $25 < 10 \sqrt{2\pi}$.  Therefore, $x = 25$ is the unique solution to the equation.